# What does $_{x \in A}$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What does $_{x \in A}$ mean?

I have found it in [this document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05741). I thought initially that the result was a vector, but in the formula it appears to be a real number.

Comment: indicator function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). Defined by
$$ _{x \in A}(y) = \begin{cases} 1 & y \in A \\ 0 & y \notin A \end{cases} $$

Alternative notation: $_A$ or $\chi_A$.

Comment: Because of $_{x\in A}(x)$ this is a very bad notation. I would go with the standard $_A$.

Comment: @amsmath I think that's mostly on me. But you're right that you naturally want to use $x$ as the input of the function and it doesn't quite work with this notation. In probability, the function often written without an argument so you can get away with putting $x \in A$ into the notation.

Comment: Even if it is written without an argument, why the $x$? Why not $t$? Or $\eta$? It just does not make any sense, is misleading, and superfluous.

Comment: An alternative notation might be the set itself, when it can't cause a problem.

Comment: I usually see $\Chi_A$ used (in optimization contexts) to denote the characteristic function. Is there a particular context in which it is commonly used to denote the indicator function?

Comment: @David I don't know. I've only ever used it myself in probability and nobody in probability is going to be writing $\chi_A$ here. We might have used it in analysis when we defined the Lebesgue integral, but I don't remember anymore. Wikipedia also just says that people use the notation without really saying who those people are.